# If $w$ is an imaginary cube root of unity, then the polynomial whose roots are $2w+3w^2$ and $2w^2 + 3w$ is?

Tags: roots, quadratics

What polynomial with complex coefficients has the following as its roots?

$2w+3w^2$ and $2w^2 + 3w$

I have tried doing this all the ways I know of, still can't get my pen over it...

Can you guys help me with this problem?

Comment: Make the question clearer. I can't see any equation there.

Comment: $(x - 2\omega - 3\omega^2)(x - 3 \omega - 2\omega^2)$?

Comment: Hint: Find the sum and product of the new roots.

Comment: Is that an equation? Where is the $=$ signal?

Comment: @UdayKiran, I have edited your question to make it clearer. I hope this is what you wanted to ask. If not then you can make the appropriate changes.

Comment: You have to define $w$. These things aren't always standard.

Comment: @R_D thanks :D .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $w$ is a primitive third root of unity.

The sum of the roots is $5w + 5w^2 = -5$ since $1 + w + w^2 = 0$.

The product of the roots is $w^2(6 + 13w + 6w^2) = w^2(13w - 6w) = 7w^3 = 7$, using the previous fact and $w^3 = 1$.

What's a polynomial with sum of roots $-5$ and product of roots $7$?